# What is this parameter? in Lyubashevsky's ID-scheme

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, lattice-crypto, soundness, completeness

I am studying Lybashevsky's ID-scheme from the article *Fiat-Shamir With Aborts: Applications to Lattice and Factoring-Based Signatures*(https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2009/59120596/59120596.pdf) by *Vadim Lybashevsky*.

I am trying to work trough the soundness and completness of the ID-scheme through the four steps offered in section **3.1**. In step 1 it is claimed that the completness (probability that an honest verifier is accepted) is $1/e$, but the parameter $e$ is not introduced nor explained at any point in the article. Is this simply referring to the soundness error (the probability that a malicious prover is able to convince an honest verifier)?

Any clues on what this $e$ is referring to and how to go forward with these steps would be much appreciated :)

Comment: It's Euler's number $e\approx 2.71828...$.

Comment: @DanielS thank you for the response. Do you know why this would be Euler's number or if this is commonly used that way within cryptography?

Comment: It's a common proportion to crop up in parameter selection where you have $m$ criteria to meet and each criterion has an independent, roughly $1-1/m$ chance of being met.

Comment: perhaps to make the justification more obvious, one can show that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{k}{m}\right)^m = e^k$ for any $k$. In particular, for $k = -1$ and large enough $m$ you expect $\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^m\approx e^{-1}$.